# Call an action method when session ends

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, session, actionmethod

I want to call LogOut action method whose View i have not created as the session times out.

I have written a script for session time out but i dont know how to call action method because all the methods i have got like `window.location` etc locates the view.

```
    <script>
            //session end

        var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout;

        var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000-55000;
        setTimeout('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);

    /* Here I want To call that AgentLogOut Method*/

        function SessionEnd() {
            alert("Session Is Going To End in 1 min Please Login Again1");

            window.location = "/Agent/AgentLogIn";
        }
</script>
```

And this the Target Controller Action to which I want to call

```
public ActionResult AgentLogOut()
        {
            string  SessionId = Session["LogInSession"].ToString();
            string OType = "LogOut";
            ProcedureName = "SP_Crud";
            XElement xl = new XElement("data",
                new XAttribute("otype", OType),
                new XElement("sessionId", SessionId),
                new XElement("agentIp", AgentIp)
                );
            objDal.ExecuteNonQuery(ProcedureName, CommandType.StoredProcedure, new MySqlParameter("@xml", xl.ToString()));
            Session.Clear();
            Session.Abandon();

            return RedirectToAction("AgentLogIn","Agent");
        }
```

I have tried all ways which i knew.Suggest me how to hit only the action method.

Comment: did you using your controller and view in the same project?

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: also bring some information about `SessionEnd()` function. it will be works correct?

Comment: Where are you calling the `AgentLogOut` action from? Your js is is setting the `window.location` to the `AgentLogIn` action

Comment: @Corporalis I am calling this at session timeout so that it can register logout time if session ends.

Comment: @Ankita when session times out it sets the path to logout view but not to Controller.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I have just configured the session time out it into web.config

Comment: but you are returning to Login method. How it is returning to Logout view?

Comment: @ankita There no view for LogOut this method interacts to database that is the problem without rendering to view i want to execute the action method.hy

Comment: Please show us your LogIn method.

Comment: @ankita this script just route the dashboard to AgentLogin. So there is nothing to show in that my problem belongs to route AgentLogout().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then you can make a ajax request like :

```
function SessionEnd() 
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/Agent/AgentLogIn",
    data:{data:value},
    success:function(response){
    //do some stuff like login page redirection
    },
    error:function(){
    //do some stuff like login page redirection
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but this render the LogOut View But I have Not Created View For logOut.

Comment: you can create a empty view as your framework requires

Comment: Yes that will work but also increases the response time.

Comment: yes , but sometimes we have to do such things as our framework demands

Answer (score 1):

```
  var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout;

    var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000-55000;
    setTimeout(function SessionEnd() {
        alert("Session Is Going To End in 1 min Please Login Again1");
       window.location = "/Agent/AgentLogIn";
    }, sTimeout);
```

OR

```
    var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout;

    var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000-55000;
    setTimeout(SessionEnd, sTimeout);



    function SessionEnd() {
        alert("Session Is Going To End in 1 min Please Login Again1");
        window.location = "/Agent/AgentLogIn";
    }
```

note make sure : you have set Session.Timeout with integer value

Comment: Script Portion is working well. Tell me how to call the action method.

Comment: have you tried window.location = "/Agent/AgentLogIn"; you should try adding base url of your project

Comment: Yes i have tried but this also needs to have a view atleast but i dont want to create a view for this i just want to call that action method and insert that data into the database.